# How to make integer input appear after rather than before message that prompts user input?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I was creating a program in which the user is repeatedly asked to enter input until the Scanner reads 0. For some odd reason whenever I enter an integer, it appears before the next message appears asking for input.Any help to resolve this is much appreciated.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");

    int number;
    int posCount = 0;
    int negCount = 0;
    int total = 0;

    while((number = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0:");
        if(number < 0) {

            negCount++; 

        }
        if(number > 0) {
            posCount++;

        }


        total += number;    
    }


    System.out.println("The number of negatives is " + negCount);
    System.out.println("The number of positives is " + posCount);
    System.out.println("The total is " + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do use `System.out.print()` isntead of `System.out.println()`.

```
System.out.print("Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: ");
```